# Load XML from documents directory - iPhone

Tags: iphone

Instead of loading a XML from the URL, I would like to load it from the documents directory(which i saved when there is Internet connection)

```
NSString* filename=@"magzine.xml";
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[URLlink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
[data writeToFile:storePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"URL: %@",url);
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
//xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];

[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser parse];
```

Now i am getting the xml from url ,that is from initwithcontentsofurl,Now i  want to get the saved file from documents directory when there is no internet connection.Please help me in this ,how to load the xml??
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=499671) is an example on how to load and parse local XML files on the iPhone.